# calling application variable from asp.net class and webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asmx

The company i work for made this executable that then returns a password for the database. I call a helper class in my code from my webservice that returns the password. The class is basically running this executable and retrieving the password.  I would like to minimize the amount of calls that i make to this executable to basically one call, in other words next service call should just use the global application variable and not the executable. I though well i can just make an application variable and store the password there and not have to deal with it. However it appears to me that i cannot set the global variable from a separate class.
This link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk34sw2t.aspx
comes very close to what i want to do but i don't want to make a service out of the password retriever. i simply would just like to grab it from the global variable and if its not set set the password. Ive tried doing  it like this from a shared class but i keep getting errors.

```
If (Not HttpContext.Current.Application("sesame")) Then
                HttpContext.Current.Application("sesame") = password

            End If
```

this for some reason gives me an http error which i dont know how to overcome. Can someone point me in the right direction. is what I'm saying feasible or I'm just of my nut.

Comment: Are u saying `HttpContext.Current.Application` is not available inside of your own class? What kind of error are u getting?

Comment: the returned error simply says httperror

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it should be something like

```
If HttpContext.Current.Application("sesame") Is Nothing Then
   HttpContext.Current.Application("sesame") = password
End If
```

Comment: and thats different from what i have how? are we evaluating the same thing?

Comment: If `HttpContext.Current.Application("sesame")` *is Nothing* attempt to use it as a Boolean (as you do now) may throw an error

Comment: thank you i didnt realize what i was doing until you pointed it out to me. I feel so dumb right now.:-D

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help. And don't feel dumb, in some languages (e.g. JavaScript) a construct like this is valid